# how to set two environment variables in nssm with command line

Tags: windows-services, nssm

I tried to set two environment variables using 
`nssm set TestService AppEnvironmentExtra SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE`
but only the last value is considered, one command overlaps the other

i try

`nssm install TestService TestPath
    nssm set SystoreApi AppEnvironmentExtra SOME_VAR1=SOME_VALUE1
    nssm set SystoreApi AppEnvironmentExtra SOME_VAR2=SOME_VALUE2`

bout only SOME_VAR2=SOME_VALUE2 was save

[imagem of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdfGd.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

When setting an environment block with `nssm set`, each variable should be specified as a `KEY=VALUE` pair in a separate argument.

[In the official documentation](https://nssm.cc/commands) under "Non-standard parameters" there is the following example:

`nssm set <servicename> AppEnvironmentExtra CLASSPATH=C:\Classes TEMP=C:\Temp`